# Process custom KPI calculations for IQueryable<T> interface exposed

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable, ignite

I have `IQueryable<T>` interface exposed by an out of process Caching framework (Apache-Ignite), for which my processing requirement is to filter, sort, paginate the data and also for filtered data numeric columns (int, double), calculate the summary KPIs like `sum, min, max, avg` as that needs to be shown in the Ui at the end of the call.

Example would be, for a `Type Person`:

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name {get;set;}

  public int Age {get;set;}

  public double Salary {get;set;}
}
```

My query looks like:

```
IQueryable<Person> personQueryable = <Fetch Queryable API>

var result = personQueryable.AsParallel()   // For Parallel Processing
                            .Where(// Apply Filter) // Filter Data
                            .OrderBy(// Order By Clause) // Sort Data
                            .Take(// Pagination) // Take a Subset of Data
```

Now the challenge, that I have though I want to Calculate the Summary KPI `(sum, min, max, avg)`, for the numeric columns `Age,Salary`, but that needs to be done on the filtered records, not the paginated, so how to accomplish the same.

One option is to bring all the filtered records into active memory (List) then calculate the KPIs, though at times filtered data could be > 100 K, thus making the response slow, any idea on how to achieve it.

In my view, I need to return a wrapper object, which at run-time calculates the KPI dynamically based on numeric columns passed, which can be stored in a Dictionary, with column name as key and KPI calls as value with all the calculations for a given column.

Also please note, currently we use In process Cache, so we do all the processing on `IEnumrable<T>`, using custom extension methods, another point I am thinking is can I simply replace `IEnumrable<T>` by `IQueryable<T>` and all the extension methods will work as is though at the out of process Cache level and I will get the final results when data is serialized to Ui.
               .

Comment: Am I right that you have all your data in Apache Ignite cache? If so, you should really use Ignite Compute APIs and calculate these values in a distributed manner rather than locally.

Comment: Ignite SQL will probably be the best way to calculate min/max/avg/sum over the whole data set, if you need that.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, are the two comments above refer to different options available. Regarding ignite SQL are there any limitation beside not working for near cache

Comment: Also please note all the operations like data fetch, filter,  sort, paginate and summary calculation is part of same call, to show composite data on UI, but as I understand they cannot be done in same call, do I need to execute two parallel / async requests to make it efficient

Comment: As I understand, you need to display one page of the data to the user (with sorting and filtering), and also avg/max/min/sum for the WHOLE data set, right? If so, I don't think it is possible to do in one call. You should do a separate call to calculate aggregates. Also, looks like you use Ignite LINQ, so SQL is already used under the hood, so you should not have a problem here.

Comment: Yes but we show only one page of data, so you suggest two parallel request for each purpose and then aggregate the results into final data structure and also we need to fire separate scalar query for each column KPI like sum, min, max, avg

Comment: Also I am not sure what Linq provider whether we can have column names supplied as string name, as in SQL since I am trying to write a generic code for number of entities with column names filled using JSON request

Comment: We are going out of topic here. You can post a separate question about Ignite LINQ/SQL.

Comment: Sure thanks but important aspect is can I run custom extension method on the Iqueryable here which does data processing for me using standard methods available in the Linq or expression trees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to retrieve one page of the data and aggregates over the whole data set in one go. You have to do two calls, one to get paged data, and one to calculate aggregates.

Looks like you use Ignite LINQ, so queries are already configured. In this case just do a separate SQL query:

`personCache.QueryFields(new SqlFieldsQuery("select min(age), max(age), avg(age), sum(age), min(salary), max(salary), avg(salary), sum(salary) from person"))`